# '[180] Job was deleted while it was executing: the outcome was (Unknown)'

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a simple package to produce a csv file from a query and update a 'lastrun' time on a table. This was written in 2014, running on a test server with 2014. The agent job that runs it simply executes it via an SSIS Package step. No other steps are involved.

However, I get the above error message in the agent log file. The job will successfully execute and produce a file, but ONLY after either restarting the agent service or changing the properties on the job (after refreshing the job list in SSMS). And because it seemingly deletes itself during execution, there is no job history to view, and then the schedule will stop repeating.

I can't find anything like this on here, and wondered if anyone has ever seen this, or has any ideas?

Thanks.

Note (update) : All other agent jobs run ok on the same server. The only difference with this one is that it's the only one that is calling an SSIS package.

Comment: How do you know the job is deleting itself?

Comment: The above error message in the log (subject of the post), and the fact that each time it runs I have to refresh the view in SSMS before going into Properties (it thinks the job doesn't exist) and the fact that there is no job history, seems to suggest that the internal id has changed and it has been deleted and recreated.
That is what I have to go on at the moment.

Comment: I mean how do you know a person isn't deleting it, or some external process isn't doing it?   What makes you think the job is deleting _itself_?

Comment: Sorry Tab, it's just a small test server. I'm the only person who has control of it. The log entry happens instantly when the job is due to start and produces a file.

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue right now and haven't yet found resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be when you try to restore the same database (subscriber/distribution) as another database name, it will clear the job automatically.